# Spring - FlatFileItemReader usage with FixedLengthTokenizer

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to read transactions from text file and then write this transactions to database with JdbcBatchItemWriter. When I use csv file and DelimitedLineTokenizer, it works fine. If I use text file and FixedLengthTokenizer, couldn't read lines because readLine() method return null in doRead() method. How can I resolve this issue. Thanks for your help.

**fileManager.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionDataFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
      scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['processPath']}"/>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="type,code"/>
                    <!--<property name="columns" value="1-12, 13-15"/>-->
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="transactionMap"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionDataFileItemWriter"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
       insert into TB_FORMAT(TYPE, CODE)
        values (:type, :code)
   ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**file.txt**

```
123         abc              
456         def
```

Comment: Have you tried to register a custom property editor for ranges (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/simple-job-launcher-context.xml#L39) ?

Comment: I found the problem, I used  this tag <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/> but I don't use header line in text file. If I use csv file this tag is neccessary. By the way I am looking custom property editor. Thank you so much.

Comment: I saw this but I assumed that it worked for you (since your example shows the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` and you said it works with it) and that you posted only the file content to show its format (without the header) for the fixed length use case. Anyway, glad you found your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - you have used DelimitedLineTokenizer , instead try using FixedLengthTokenizer

```
<bean id="transactionDataFileItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="resource"
        value="#{jobParameters['processPath']}" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.io.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="type,code" />
                    <property name="columns" value="1-12, 13-15" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="transactionMap" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I forgot to write FixedLengthTokenizer instead of DelimitedLineTokenizer, thank you for this answer.

Comment: @Ashish - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674370/caused-by-org-springframework-batch-item-file-transform-incorrectlinelengthexce ?